# How to define a variable with an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a discord.py bot that is trying to read a different entry to a postgresql table depending on what argument is given in the command. For example, if one was to do $playtime penguin then it would give the entry in minutes_played for the account 'penguin'. Here is what I have so far.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import asyncpg

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def playtime(ctx, arg):

    arg = name()

    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://{POSTGRES USERNAME/PASSWORD}@localhost/postgres')
    playtime = await conn.fetchrow(
        "SELECT minutes_played FROM public.penguin WHERE username = name();")
    await ctx.send(playtime)

bot.run('{BOT TOKEN}')
```

This however, does not work as it does not define name(). I want name() to be defined as the argument the discord user gave on the command, eg penguin. How would I go about defining name() as the argument given in the discord command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the documentation the `arg` should contain the name provided as the first argument for the command. Also make sure to use parametrized queries to avoid [sql injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The following code should work:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import asyncpg

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def playtime(ctx, arg):
    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://{POSTGRES USERNAME/PASSWORD}@localhost/postgres')
    playtime = await conn.fetchrow(
        "SELECT minutes_played FROM public.penguin WHERE username = $1;", arg)
    await ctx.send(playtime)

bot.run('{BOT TOKEN}')
```

You probably also want to add some error handling code if wrong name is passed to the command.

---

References:

[1] https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

[2] https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html